# Documentation Tour page gives no indication that Documentation has been discontinued

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

Visiting https://stackoverflow.com/tour/documentation gives no indication that documentation has been discontinued.

Comment: soon... There is a lot of things like this they're updating. (This should be one of the first ones, i agree)

Comment: I'm not sure this is truly a "can no longer be reproduced" question. Someone could accidentally fat-finger the old Documentation tour back into existence. Tours as a site feature still exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whoops, that's an oversight. Sorry about that. The tour will have the same banner we show on other Documentation pages starting with the next prod build.